# Joomla joomsef issue

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

For me, Joomsef is working for most of the links. I have moved my website to a new host and it is showing 404 for only some links. My client actually linked using itemid only and these links are showing 404.

For eg : index.php?Itemid=216 is redirecting incorrectly. It is not taking the category section. It has to be redirected to healing/main-lessons.html, but it is redirecting to mainlessons.html only and showing 404. How can I fix this?

Only URLs in the categosy healing has got this issue I think. I have .htaccess enabled and Rewritebase is correct. Also there is no changes to any other sections as I copied the complete DB and site files.

Comment: This domain is actually added as an addon domain to the new server. If I use the complete url for the domian, I mean healing.xxxxx.org/index.php?Itemid-216 everything is working fine. Need to change something somewhere But don;t know what is . Please help me,

Comment: What is an addon domain? Is your domain in the root? if not, the entire joomsef database will contain invalid data. And if it's not in the root, any call to the old urls i.e. example.com/index.php will invoke another joomla installation.

Comment: my domain is in public_html/healingstreamsusa folder. So how can I regenerate the SEO links then ?

Comment: is there another domain in the root? (i.e. in public_html?) was the domain previously with the same prefix? there are several aspects we are unaware of which would make quite a difference, you will have at least two .htaccess files (public_html and public-html/healingstreamsusa ) to handle

Comment: @RiccardoZorn yes. The thing is that my main domain is hosted in public_html folder and then I created one add on domain using cpanel. Then it has created another folder inside public_html. Yeah I have 2 .htaccess files one is used for the main site and the one inside healingstreamsusa is used for that aite.

Comment: by the way, the issue is with articles in one category only. All other internal links are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this. I have added aliases for each of the link in this category. Used a php script to fetch all the links in healing category and this itemid links are added as aliases to real links . These is added to joomsef_aliases table and now everything is working fine. :)